# Drone simulators for designing and flying aircraft?

Tags: simulators

Is there any free software that can design drones/aircraft and test fly them? Thank you. I’m looking for a software with no controller needed, just to test if the aircraft/drone can hover with stability.

Comment: Flying an aircraft without controller required is quite the challenging endeavor, especially for multirotors.

Comment: I'm referring to a simulator that test to see if the aircraft/drone can fly with stability, though in my case it's more of a hover

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not quite sure what kind of drone you'd like to build. However, here are the ones I use for a variety of multirotor and fixed-wing drones:

- I love [CoppeliaSim](https://www.coppeliarobotics.com/) (formerly V-REP) for multitorotors. It makes it very easy to make certain assumptions about forces and torques, and to see the results in real-time.
- [X-Plane](https://www.x-plane.com/) is great for fixed-wing drones. X-Plane simulates flight dynamics on a fluid-dynamics level so it's actually simulating the plane as it would fly based on its geometry.